# Getting local 2D coordinates of vertices of a planar polygon in 3D space

Tags: python, 3d, geometry

I have several planar polygons that are defined by their vertices in 3D space. These polygons are rotated randomly in 3 Dimensions.

Now I would like to work with each of these polygons vertices in their own local 2D space. I don't really care where the center of this local space is. I just need the x & y axis to be orthogonal to the polygons normal.

So for example, if i had a polygon that is a rectangle of width & height 1, the Vertices could look like:

```
v1 = [-0.558013, -0.0334937, -0.433013]
v2 = [0.308013, 0.466506, -0.433013]
v3 = [-0.308013, -0.466506, 0.433013]
v4 = [0.558013, 0.0334937, 0.433013]
```

but I would like them to look like this:

```
v1 = [0, 0]
v2 = [0, 1]
v3 = [1, 1]
v4 = [1, 0]
```

So my question is, how do I convert each vertices 3D coordinates to local 2D coordinates?

Comment: Seems that in the example case, you're also wanting the local x & y axes to be parallel with some of the polygon's edges. Otherwise there are many equivalent sets of 2D coordinates possible depending on the rotation of polygon with respect to the origin of chosen 2D coordinate system.

Comment: @martineau You're right but the rotation around the local z axis doesn't really matter in my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You start by first considering three non-collinear points of the polygon `p0`, `p1` and `p2`, then you compute

```
loc0 = p0                       # local origin
locx = p1 - loc0                # local X axis
normal = cross(locx, p2 - loc0) # vector orthogonal to polygon plane
locy = cross(normal, locx)      # local Y axis
```

where `cross` is the cross product operator:

```
def cross(a, b):
    return P3d(a.y*b.z - a.z*b.y,
               a.z*b.x - a.x*b.z,
               a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x)
```

then you normalize the computed local axis `locx` and `locy`

```
locx /= locx.length()
locy /= locy.length()
```

and finally the local coordinates for the points are simply

```
local_coords = [(dot(p - loc0, locx),  # local X coordinate
                 dot(p - loc0, locy))  # local Y coordinate
                for p in points]
```

where `dot` is the scalar product operator:

```
def dot(a, b):
    return a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y + a.z*b.z
```

To go back from local coordinates `(Lx, Ly)` to 3D the transformation is

```
p = loc0 + Lx*locx + Ly*locy
```

[image: Picture showing points and vectors used in formulas]

Comment: I found this to be a very succinct and understandable explanation. Does this procedure have a name of any sort?

Answer (score 3):

For one polygon, you need to find a local 2D basis in the plane of the polygon and project the 3D coordinates of each vertex of the polygon on this 2D basis to get 2D coordinates. In what follows I also assume you're looking for an orthonormal 2D basis (unit length and orthogonal 2D basis vectors on the polygon plane).

Step by step:

1. Compute the (unit) normal n of the polygon, assuming the vertices are indeed coplanar,
2. Take the first edge of the polygon and use it to define the first axis u (unit vector) of the 2D basis,
3. Complete the 2D basis with another axis v using the u and n (v = n x u)
4. Project each vertex on the (u, v, n) 3D basis, this will give its 2D coordinates in the plane of the polygon.

For instance, with the following polygon with five vertices:

```
   M1 +----+ M3
      |      \
      |       + M4
      |      /
   M2 +----+ M5
```

where `M1` has 3D coordinates `v1 = (x1, y1, z1)` and `M2` has 3D coordinates `v2 = (x2, y2, z2)`, etc...

1. The unit normal to the plane is: `n = (v2 - v1) x (v3 - v1) / |(v2 - v1) x (v3 - v1)|`
2. The first axis of the 2D basis is: `u = (v2 - v1) / |(v2 - v1)|`
3. The second axis of the 2D basis is: `v = n x u`
4. Take a vertex of the polygon (or any point in the polygon plane), for instance `M5`.

   Then its 3D coordinates can be written in the `(u, v, n)` basis with origin `v1`.

   ```
     v5 = v1 + r5 * u + s5 * v + t5 * n


               (           ) ( r5 )   (  xu  xv  xn ) ( r5 )   (     ) ( r5 ) 
     v5 - v1 = (  u  v  n  ) ( s5 ) = (  yu  yv  yn ) ( s5 ) = (  B  ) ( s5 ) 
               (           ) ( t5 )   (  zu  zv  zn ) ( t5 )   (     ) ( t5 )
   ```

   where `t5` should be 0 (it's the coordinate of the point along the normal of the plane, so if the point lies on the plane of the polygon, it's 0).

   So, solving for `(r5, s5, t5)` yields:

   ```
     ( r5 )                                    (  u  )
     ( s5 ) = B^-1 (v5 - v1) = B^T (v5 - v1) = (  v  ) ( v5 - v1 )
     ( t5 )                                    (  n  )
   ```

   Because B is an orthogonal matrix (so B^-1 = B^T).

   In the end, one simply has:

   ```
     r5 = u . (v5 - v1)
     s5 = v . (v5 - v1)
   ```

   where `.` is the vector dot product.